# Cplex warm start

Tags: optimization, cplex

Can warm starting Cplex change the precision of the solution?

I set up different initial state in the following get. Always come up with the same solution.

```
from qiskit_optimization import QuadraticProgram
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from qiskit_optimization.algorithms import MinimumEigenOptimizer, CplexOptimizer
from qiskit_optimization.translators import from_docplex_mp

mdl = Model()

x = [mdl.continuous_var(0,1,"x%s" % i) for i in range(len(Sigma_PD))]

objective = mdl.sum([Mu[0][i] * x[i] for i in range(len(Sigma_PD))])
objective -= 2 * mdl.sum(
    [Sigma_PD[i, j] * x[i] * x[j] for i in range(len(Sigma_PD)) for j in range(len(Sigma_PD))]
)

warmstart=mdl.new_solution()
warmstart.add_var_value(x[0],0.01)
warmstart.add_var_value(x[1],0.05)
warmstart.add_var_value(x[2],0.08)
warmstart.add_var_value(x[5],1)
mdl.add_mip_start(warmstart)

mdl.maximize(objective)

sol=mdl.solve(log_output=True)

mdl.solve()    

for v in mdl.iter_continuous_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Is there any way to increase the precision of the solution obtained by Cplex with warm-starting technique?

Answer (score 0):

To set the gap (precision) you can use

```
parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap
```

If you want to get several solutions, you can use the solution pool within cplex

Tiny example at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooenumerate.py

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

from cplex.exceptions import CplexError, CplexSolverError

def make_bus_model(**kwargs):
    mdl = Model(name='buses', **kwargs)
    nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
    nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
    mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
    mdl.minimize(nbbus40*460 + nbbus30*360)
    mdl.parameters.mip.pool.intensity=4
    mdl.apply_parameters()
    return mdl


def generate_soln_pool(mdl):
    cpx = mdl.get_cplex()
    try:
        cpx.populate_solution_pool()
    except CplexSolverError:
        print("Exception raised during populate")
        return []
    numsol = cpx.solution.pool.get_num()
    print("The solution pool contains %d solutions." % numsol)
    meanobjval = cpx.solution.pool.get_mean_objective_value()
    print("The average objective value of the solutions is %.10g." %
          meanobjval)

    nb_vars = mdl.number_of_variables
    sol_pool = []
    for i in range(numsol):
        objval_i = cpx.solution.pool.get_objective_value(i)

        x_i = cpx.solution.pool.get_values(i)
        assert len(x_i) == nb_vars
        sol = mdl.new_solution()
        for k in range(nb_vars):
            vk = mdl.get_var_by_index(k)
            sol.add_var_value(vk, x_i[k])
        sol_pool.append(sol)
    return sol_pool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bm = make_bus_model()
    pool = generate_soln_pool(bm)
    for s, sol in enumerate(pool,start=1):
        print(" this is solution #{0} of the pool".format(s))
        sol.display()
```